# ExtJS panel crashes when removeAll() calling frequently

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a panel for list feed items in child panels. I need to remove all items from panel before feed filter action. My code is below and it works correctly, but when filter action calling frequently, application crashes.

```
filter:function(){
//
.... some process before filtering
///
    var panel=this.lookupReference('feedsPanel');
    panel.removeAll();//<-- Application crashes this line

    var items=[];
    for(var i=0; i<mStore.data.items.length;i++){
        var item= Ext.create('MyApp.view.custom.FeedCard',{
                mdata:mStore.data.items[i]
            });
        items.push(item);
    }
    panel.add(items);
    panel.doLayout();
}
```

And eror is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null  ........ ext-all-debug.js:22567
```

Framework: ExtJS 5.1

Comment: You need to post a test case.

Comment: Appreciate if you can put up a fiddle...

Comment: Looks like something is trying to set style on your panels after they have been removed. To track it down, locate that line 22567 in ext-all-debug.js and insert something like: `if (!foo) {
        console.trace();
    }`
`foo` being the actual variable reported `null` in your crash error message (most likely it is called `dom`). Once you see the trace you'll find what is trying to set style on your panel when it shouldn't.